# Merge 2 dataframes with a matching columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge 2 dataframes. My code is as follows;
import pandas as pd

```
from IPython.display import display

dt1 = {
    'aa': ['j', 'b', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'c'],
    "ab": [4, 2, 5, 6, 1, 7],
}

dt2 = {
    'aa': ['b', 'e', 'i', 'j', 'c', 'g'],
    "ac": [4, 9, 5, 8, 3, 4],
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dt1)
display(df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dt2)
display(df2)
```

My expected output is like this;

```
  aa  ab  ac
0  j   4   8
1  b   2   4
2  e   5   9
3  g   6   4
4  i   1   5
5  c   7   3
```

Comment: These are questions with one line solutions and have been asked as nauseam. Please vote to close, or do a quick Google search for duplicates before answering. It's the decent thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do a left merge to keep every row of df1: `pd.merge(df1,df2,'left')`

Output:

```
  aa  ab  ac
0  j   4   8
1  b   2   4
2  e   5   9
3  g   6   4
4  i   1   5
5  c   7   3
```

Comment: How do you know that OP needs a LEFT merge?

Comment: The expected output is the result of a left merge

Comment: You can get the same result with an inner or a right join/merge.